# How can I load - inflate items to a Recycler view without locking the UI or showing a load icon?

Tags: android-recyclerview

I just want to be able to display a list of contacts (without even communicating to a server) just the way it is displayed on the "Contacts" native app on the phone.

I have like 1500 contacts and when I try to load the recycler view, all items at once, it lags a lot 2 - 3 seconds.

I've achieved loading more items but with a loading bar and thats not what I want.

I've already tried Threads, Executors, postOnUIThread(), handler.post() and even AsyncTask -> Override -> doOnBackground. Nothing works.

```
private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    int inserted;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        //Do some work
        try {
            lcf.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((BaseActivity) lcf.getActivity()).showProgressDialog();
                }
            });
            int currentSize = contactsLoaded.size();
            for (inserted = 0; inserted < lcf.getController().getContacts().size() && contactsLoaded.size() < lcf.getController().getContacts().size(); inserted++) {
                contactsLoaded.add(lcf.getController().getContacts().get(currentSize + inserted));
                notifyItemRangeInserted(contactsLoaded.size() - 1, inserted);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        //Print Toast or open dialog
        //notifyItemRangeInserted(contactsLoaded.size() - 1, 0);
        if(!lcf.getController().isSelectedAffiliated()){
            lcf.disclaimerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            lcf.disclaimerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        lcf.isLoading=false;
        ((BaseActivity) lcf.getActivity()).hideProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

That code lives within my adapter, "lcf" is a reference to the fragment. If I use the already loaded list saved on the controller (that I get from the fragment reference) and then just call notifyDataSetChanged() it LAGS like hell. So with this CustomTask I tried to load every item and notify it one by one to a Background task hoping it would make the items pop up quickly and sequentially without interfereing with the UI thread to not freeze the screen. It doesn't work. I am out of options now. I've tried everything.

Comment: Did you try with 10-15 contacts only? Does it still take time? In my experience, the number of items shouldn't determine the rendering time of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: yeah with 15 is instant